# Storing Matrix information in STL vector. Which is better vector or vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, matrix

I've created my own Matrix class were inside the class the information regarding the Matrix is stored in a STL vector.  I've notice that while searching the web some people work with a vector of vectors to represent the Matrix information.  My best guess tells me that so long as the matrix is small or skinny (row_num >> column_num) the different should be small, but what about if the matrix is square or fat (row_num << column_num)?  If I were to create a very large matrix would I see a difference a run time?  Are there other factors that need to be considered?

Thanks

Comment: In case your Matrix class is for numeric values only: You should consider using std::valarray instead. Using slices and arithmetic operators on slices may make things easier.

Comment: If you already have something that meets your needs, I wouldn't worry about it. Is there some concern you have about your existing class?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an off-the-shelf matrix representation such as boost's instead of reinventing the wheel?

If you have a lot of empty rows for example, using the nested representation could save a lot of space. Unless you have specific information in actual use cases showing one way isn't meeting your requirements, code the way that's easiest to maintain and implement properly.

Comment: For what I'm doing I only need multiplication, transpose, inverse (Cholesky Decomp.) and possibly addition.  So I'm trying to get ride of as much overhead as possible. I   If I had more experience with arrays.  I would probably go that route.  Also, the matrix will be dense.  Some of the matices will be near 10,000 by 10,000, and there will be a lot of these matrices.

Comment: I've tried boost at it gets really slow when they get to 10,000x10,000.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables to answer your question.

Create an abstraction so that your code does not care how the matrix is represented.  Then write your code using any implementation.  Then profile it.

If your matrix is dense, the "vector of vectors" is very unlikely to be faster than a single big memory block and could be slower.  (Chasing two pointers for random access + worse locality.)

If your matrices are large and sparse, the right answer to your question is probably "neither".

So create an abstract interface, code something up, and profile it.  (And as @Mark says, there are lots of third-party libraries you should probably consider.)

Comment: The matrices are dense, positive definite, and very large (some 10,000x10,000).

Comment: Then the key to performance is going to be good locality in your algoirithms, regardless of the underlying representation.  For top performance, you will need to understand your system's cache hierarchy and write your algorithms to exploit it.  Choose your representation to make that task easier...

Comment: Hard to fit details in a comment...  I would start by reading [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).  Bascially, the L1 cache is 5-10 times faster than L2, which is 5-10 times faster than L3, which is 5-10 times faster than DRAM.  You need to know how big these are and how your CPU manages them to write high-performance vector code.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't even know that I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 0):

If you store everything in a single vector, an iterator will traverse the entire matrix. If you use a vector of vectors, an iterator will only traverse a single dimension.